# puppeteer waitUntil: continue with loaded page after timeout

Tags: puppeteer

Puppeteer has a handy option for waiting until just 2 network requests are executed in the last 500ms:

```
let response = await page.goto(url, { waitUntil:"networkidle2" , timeout:10000});
```

I use a timeout so that I am not stuck forever. The problem with timeout is that it throws an error when no time is left. Instead, I'd like to continue with the page I currently have. Sure I can start a new `page.goto`, but now I have wasted precious time.

Is it possible to configure puppeteer to not throw when the timeout is passed and just assign to response what is currently loaded?

Comment: Can you just `try`/`catch` the error and move on? If long-running requests are blocking the load, maybe consider `domcontentloaded` rather than `networkidle2`, depending on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @ggorlen if you use try catch,  `response` (see above code line) will not be set, because `page.goto` threw an error.

Comment: I use response to find about redirect chain etc..

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying. Yeah, I'd suggest doing `domcontentloaded` and monitoring the network requests yourself. It's still unclear what your large-scale scraping/page manipulation goals are here, because there might be a much better approach that circumvents whatever you're struggling with here entirely.